# How to access/reset microphone for zoom

Tags: microphone

Using zoom on 18.04.2 I frequently encounter problems with the microphone. Within zoom, there are several possibilities to see if the microphone works: From the "manage participants" where microphone activity is shown to actual tests when joining and during a meeting.  In all situations the speakers do work but the microphone often does not.

What I have tried so far:

- quitting & restarting zoom does not work
- nor quitting the browser which calls zoom.
- switching users and logging out does not work
- restarting Ubuntu does not work either
- only Power Off and restarting anew seems to work

Is there any simpler method to reset the microphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu Studio 20.02.4, I encountered the same problem, either using Jackd or not.

Turns out that Zoom's input was muted in Ubuntu. So here's what to do to solve this benign (yet frustrating) situation :

1. Start a zoom meeting (or open the "audio" settings in zoom).
2. Open **UBUNTU**'s SETTINGS.
3. Go to the "SOUND" tab.
4. In the "VOLUME LEVELS" section, make sure that "ZOOM VoiceEngine" is at its maximum level. [if you don't see "ZOOM VoiceEngine", that's because you haven't followed "step 1" ;)]

That's it!

Below, a screenshot of said settings.

[image: A screenshot of said settings]